# Anova with three factors- interactions and further analysis?

Tags: anova

I have an experiment design which comprises of 3 different materials, treated with 3 conditions and a control at 3 different depths. The variable I am measuring is onset oxidation temperatures (OOT).
I am using ANOVA and my model in r is the following:

```
model3 <-lm(OOT~Condition*Material+Depth, data=mydata)
Anova(model3, type="III")
```

which gives me the following result

```
Anova Table (Type III tests)
Response: OOT
                   Sum Sq Df   F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)         81635  1 9841.0979 < 2.2e-16 ***
Condition             243  3    9.7466 2.023e-05 ***
Material             5357  2  322.9044 < 2.2e-16 ***
Depth                 339  2   20.4496 1.168e-07 ***
Condition:Material    930  6   18.6753 1.241e-12 ***
Residuals             556 67                        
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Is there a difference if I change the way the factors are listed in the model?
eg:

```
model5<-lm(OOT~Material*Depth+Condition, data=mydata)
Anova(model5, type="III")
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: OOT
               Sum Sq Df   F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)    147666  1 7240.1171 < 2.2e-16 ***
Material        23035  2  564.7184 < 2.2e-16 ***
Depth             275  2    6.7302  0.002137 ** 
Condition         698  3   11.4143 3.634e-06 ***
Material:Depth     78  4    0.9562  0.437172    
Residuals        1407 69                        
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I am wondering if I need to use an interaction or not?
I tested without interaction using the following model:

```
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: OOT
            Sum Sq Df    F value    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept) 204881  1 10069.5705 < 2.2e-16 ***
Condition      698  3    11.4417 3.112e-06 ***
Material     68275  2  1677.7898 < 2.2e-16 ***
Depth          339  2     8.3374 0.0005481 ***
Residuals     1485 73                         
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I have added a plot of my data [image: Boxplot facet grid]

I am getting confused, and I also needed help to understand what next? I am thinking that to be able to see what conditions had the greatest effect, or what material was the most affected, or the depth at which samples were most affected I need to do a post-hoc test, I tried Tukey's but it didn't work.

```
 posthoc <-lsmeans (model5, pairwise ~ Material * Depth + Condition,
+                    adjust="tukey")
Cld(posthoc,
+     alpha=.05,
+     letters=letters)
Error in Cld(posthoc, alpha = 0.05, letters = letters) : 
  could not find function "Cld"
```

Sorry it is a lengthy post,

Thanks

WinD

Comment: Formatted output for legibility.  Put four spaces at beginning of each line of output. Seems all went well, but please check that I didn't mess it up.

Comment: Check the data. It seems you have 4 conditions, instead of 3 conditions as you stated.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I didn't mention that I had a control as well. So basically 4 conditions. Thanks for the edit- it makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Whether you include an interaction term or not should be determined by theory and your research questions rather than model fit or significance value associated with that interaction -- do not cherry-pick significant effects. If you want to look at the differences between the different levels of your categorical predictor variables, then yes you should consider multiple comparisons using, for example, Tukey adjustment.

Critically, if you have interaction effects in your models, most packages (I think) by default will not consider multiple comparisons for all levels of interacted variables. I am not familiar with lsmeans, but from quickly looking it up it appears to have been superseded by emmeans (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/emmeans.pdf). You can use multcomp, specifically function call ghlt to run multiple comparisons (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/multcomp.pdf). However, with interaction effects you may have to define a contrast matrix for multiple comparisons which will allow you to examine the differences between the levels of one categorical variable at different values/levels of another variable. To do this I would advise you to consider the output of your linear model rather than just the ANOVA table.